# Cannot autocomplete return value with Sublime CodeIntel and JavaScript

Tags: sublimetext2

I've been looking for a light weight IDE for writing game in javascript with cocos2d-html5 framework and I found sublime text a really good choice.

I am using Sublime Text 2 and I have installed package control and Sublime CodeIntel successfully.

Then I created a folder in my game project with a config file containing the framework path:

```
{
   "JavaScript": {
      "javascriptExtraPaths": [
         "xxx/xxx/xxx/Cocos2d-html5-v2.1.4/cocos2d"
      ]
   }
}
```

But here is the problem:

Here is part of the code:

```
this.cliLayer = CLILayer.create(700, 250);
this.cliLayer.addLog("log");
```

If I "Ctrl+Click" at the “CLILayer” then the "CLILayer.js" file will be opened correctly.
Then I "Ctrl+Click" the "addLog" hoping that it will bring me the to the definition inside the
CLILayer.js but it just gives me a warning saying:

```
"Evaluation this.cliLayer.addLog ...... could not resolve first part of this.cliLayer.addLog".
```

Answer (score 1):

Like all dynamic language static analysis, SublimeCodeIntel has shortcomings what comes to symbol definition scanning. In this case it cannot resolve the type of `this.cliLayer` because the type of `this` cannot be known.

For more information about how to tune it and alternative addons please see this blog post of mine.

http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/03/04/javascript-autocompletions-and-having-one-for-sublime-text-2/